# ExtJS 5 - Error using ext-all-debug.js

Tags: javascript, extjs, xpages

I am getting following error using extjs 5.

Object doesnt support this method on line 11130 which is below

```
doc.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', me.onReadyEvent, false)
```

Here is the markup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.6.1/dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="locale: 'en-us'"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.6.1/ibm/xsp/widget/layout/layers/xspClientDojo.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/domjava/xsp/theme/webstandard/xsp.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/domjava/xsp/theme/webstandard/xspLTR.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/domjava/xsp/theme/webstandard/xspIE78.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ext-5.0.0/build/packages/ext-theme-classic/build/resources/ext-theme-classic-all-debug.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ext-5.0.0/build/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ext-5.0.0/build/packages/ext-theme-classic/build/resources/ext-theme-classic-debug.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/racer/cmg/ub_racer.nsf/customGrid.css">
</head>
<body class="xspView tundra">
<form id="view:_id1" method="post" action="/racer/cmg/ub_racer.nsf/ExtJS5Test.xsp" class="xspForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Couldnt figure out what i am missing.  Appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Set "pause on exceptions" in your Chrome DevTools and walk up the stack trace. That should shed some light on what is causing the problem.

Comment: Have you tested with different browsers?

Comment: @SerdarBasegmez - yes it works in firefox but not in IE8.  Extjs 5 documentation says it supports IE8 so not quite sure what the issue is.  Will test it on IE11 and see if it works there.

Comment: IE8 should be in standards mode according to EXTJS documentation. So make sure that it doesn't get into compatibility mode. The problem does not seem to be XPages-related. Because .addEventListener method doesn't exist in IE7.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of other errors with interrelated code because all the JavaScript for the NSF by default gets aggregated into a single file. I'm not sure if that's the problem for you here, but it might be worth seeing if it works with that switched off. In case you re not sure where to do that, it's in Xsp Properties, the checkbox for "Use runtime optimized JavaScript and CSS resources".

Comment: The resources are not aggregated as far as I can see from the HTML source